# Building & running a Dockerfile in IntelliJ

Tags: docker, intellij-idea

My Problem is the following:

If i type this in the command console, it works:

```
docker build -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile.jvm -t hello . & docker run --name hello --rm -p 8080:8080 hello
```

But if i try to use it with the "Run-Option" in IntelliJ, it doesnt work.
My command above has 9 Steps like the IntelliJ one, but it seems that the 5th fails. Here is the config:
[image: config]

Here the output from the failed build:
[image: failed build]

Here from the successful one:
[image: sucessful build]

It doesnt even create the Image-Tag like my manual command does.

And last but not least here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM fabric8/java-alpine-openjdk11-jre:latest

ENV JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
ENV AB_ENABLED=jmx_exporter

# Be prepared for running in OpenShift too
RUN adduser -G root --no-create-home --disabled-password 1001 \
  && chown -R 1001 /deployments \
  && chmod -R "g+rwX" /deployments \
  && chown -R 1001:root /deployments

COPY target/lib/* /deployments/lib/
COPY target/*-runner.jar /deployments/app.jar
EXPOSE 8080

# run with user 1001
USER 1001

ENTRYPOINT [ "/deployments/run-java.sh" ]
```

Where is the key Difference? I can stick with the manual one, but the Run-Config would be smoother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 3 files in your build context. It seems weird. You might want to specify the "Context folder" option

Comment: Thanks! Now it builds and runs. Didnt really think of that. But one Problem stays: If i run it twice, it doesnt delete the old image, but creates a new without a tag. My manual deletes the old and creates the new. How can i make that happen in IntelliJ? cause deleteing it everytime per hand doesnt make it better than doing all manually

Comment: Running docker build never deletes the old image, it merely changes its name to <none>. You do have to delete them by hand, or run a simple `docker system prune`

Comment: --force-rm on build is the solution here. @Faeeria but the manual always created a new one, never had the Problem with that way

Comment: Are you sure it deletes the old image ? It is supposed to delete only the intermediate containers

Comment: You can always add the --force-rm to the `Build options` section

Comment: at least i didnt even know the option, but it always created a new container and deleted the old. I used the command stated above